# Django DetailView

Tags: python, django

i am a beginner in Django. i have the below simple django model (refer to below). My list view has worked perfectly fine in the https://localhost/simpleapp/. However, when i try DetailView via https:local host/simpleapp/1, it gives me a 404 cant found. I don't know where is the problem as i already defined the urls wit the regular expression ^(?P\d+)/$.

Model.py

```
class University(models.Model):
    university_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.university_name

class Student(models.Model):
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    university = models.ForeignKey(University, on_delete=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Views.py

```
class StudentList(generic.ListView):
    model = models.Student
    context_object_name = 'student_list'
    template_name = 'simpleapp/student_list.html'


class StudentDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = models.Student
    context_object_name = 'student_detail'
    template_name = 'simpleapp/student_detail.html'
```

urls.py in app folder

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.StudentList.as_view(), name='student_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.StudentDetail.as_view(), name='student_detail'),

]
```

urls.py in project folder

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.Index.as_view(), name='index' ),
    url(r'^simpleapp/$', include('simpleapp.urls', namespace='simpleapp')),
]
```

student_detail.html

```
{% extends 'simpleapp/student_base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h1> {{student_detail}}</h1>

{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
url(r'^simpleapp/$', include('simpleapp.urls', namespace='simpleapp')),
```

Here Django will match all urls which begin with `simepleapp/` (because of the beginning `^`) and ends with it as well (because of the ending `$`).

`/simpleapp/1` is not matched by the url matcher.

instead, try changing the url to

```
url(r'^simpleapp/', include('simpleapp.urls', namespace='simpleapp')),
```

this way, Any url starting with `simepleapp` will be matched

Answer (score 0):

You have a `$` at the end of the pattern that includes the simpleapp urls, which means nothing more will be matched. So the basic /simpleapp/ URL works, but anything after that won't. Remove that $; only use it on full patterns, not includes.